# TypeError: ethers.Contract is not a constructor

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, ethers.js, decentralized-applications

I am using ethersjs library to create a contract.
I used the following line:

```
contract = new ethers.Contract(address, ERC20_ABI, provider);
```

it has worked in the past always but now I am getting the following error:

```
TypeError: ethers.Contract is not a constructor
```

How to solve this

Answer (score -1):

```
import { ethers } from "ethers";

 const contract = new ethers.Contract(
      address,
      abi,
      provider
    );
```